# Epiphytic(?) Cactus Identification Needed

Tags: identification, houseplants, succulents, cactus

[Epiphtye-like cactus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NpYM.jpg)
Got it while picking up a Moonglow graptoveria at a local greenhouse. This sad little epiphytic guy  looked way out of place among the golden barrel seedlings.
Unfortunately there weren't any flowers on it and it was being sold with an "assorted succulent" tag like the rest. Doesn't really look like any of the orchid or Thanksgiving/Christmas/Easter ones I've seen before, however.

It's kinda wilted and beaten up, but I think it stands a chance as it perked up after a little water.

Edit- typo

Comment: Can't ID, but the condition doesn't look too bad. I'd repot it in some cactus soil and get rid of that peat. Get a bigger, hanging pot and stand back!

Comment: It looks like any one of thousands of epiphyllum hybrids. Just wait to see what colour flowers you get - but unless they are very unusual, don't expect that to identify the exact cultivar either.